# PUT request to upload a file not working in Flask

Tags: python, http, flask, http-method, http-put

I am working on a web application using Flask. One of the views is supposed to accept uploaded files through PUT requests, however I only can get POST requests with `$ curl -F upload=@filename URL` to work properly. With PUT requests such as `$ curl --upload-file filenname URL` the `request.files` ImmutableMultiDict is empty. Am I missing something in Flask or maybe with using curl?

Comment: I don't think this question should have been marked as a duplicate. *This* question is specifically about using HTTP PUT with Flask to upload files. The linked question is about getting data from HTTP POST/GET requests. Neither the linked question nor any of its current answers talks about HTTP PUT. Not sure if there's a process for getting it unmarked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PUT request is way different compared to POST request. With PUT request the file contents can be accessed using either [`request.data`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.data) or [`request.stream`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.stream). The first one stores incoming data as string, while `request.stream` acts more like a file object, making it more suitable for binary data:

```
with open('uploaded_image.jpg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(request.stream.read())
```

Comment: Yes my file ended up in request.data because Flask cannot handle its mime type.